# Detect version of Java runtime used internally by IntelliJ 2019?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, version

The [early access version of IntelliJ 2019.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) is available with either Java 8 or Java 11 bundled as the Java runtime used internally.

[image: screenshot of the download page on the JetBrains.com site for Early Access version of IntelliJ 2019.1]

➥ How can I verify the version of Java being used *internally* by IntelliJ?

To be clear: I am talking about **the JVM bundled with IntelliJ**. I am *not* asking about how to specify the version of Java to be used for compiling or running my own app which I am programming using IntelliJ.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Simply because is always good to know your tooling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "About IntelliJ IDEA" menu entry shows this.

(For 2018.3 on MacOS)

[image: intellij idea about box]